# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named X although the module does exist

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very strange error with Python.

```
python main1.py                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                
  File "main1.py", line 1, in <module>                                                            
    from sfr import hello                                                             
  File "C:\sfr\hello.py", line 1, in <module>                          
    from constants1 import OBJECT_NAME                                                 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants1'
```

My main1.py looks like this

```
from sfr import hello                                                                                                                                   
print('Hello World')
```

type sfr\hello.py

```
from constants1 import OBJECT_NAME
```

type sfr\constants1.py

```
OBJECT_NAME = 'salesforce_object_name'
```

I am unable to fathom this why am i getting no module named constants1 ?
The constants1.py is located in sfr folder

Comment: have you create `__init__.py` under sfr ?

Comment: Hmm i am told in python3.7 __init__.py is not required anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running the main1.py file from the parent directory (outside `sfr`), the import path should be from the base. That is,

```
from sfr.constants1 import OBJECT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give imports from the root path of your project. If sfr is a package at root level, your statement should be:

```
from sfr.constants1 import OBJECT_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at the problem that was indeed the issue